# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI

Tags: java, jai, geotools

I recently started my first program with GeoTools in which i was also using JAI- Java Advanced Imaging 1_1_2_01 with JDK 1_7. **It worked fine until I added GeoTiff Jars**. I found following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI
>       at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.read(GeoTiffReader.java:607)
>       at com.rgb.PixelExtractor.extract(PixelExtractor.java:55)
>       at com.rgb.RGBSpliter.main(RGBSpliter.java:136)

The Code is as below

```
 public void extract(File f, String name, String date) throws Exception {
 ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY
        .createValue();
 policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);

 // this will basically read 4 tiles worth of data at once from the disk...
 ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
 //gridsize.setValue(512 * 4 + "," + 512);

 // Setting read type: use JAI ImageRead (true) or ImageReaders read methods (false)
 ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
 useJaiRead.setValue(true);

 //reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[] { policy, gridsize, useJaiRead });
 // The line that throws error
 GridCoverage2D image
        = new GeoTiffReader(f).read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
 Rectangle2D bounds2D = image.getEnvelope2D().getBounds2D();
 bounds2D.getCenterX();
// calculate zoom level for the image
GridGeometry2D geometry = image.getGridGeometry();



BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
// ColorModel colorModel = img.getColorModel(      
WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();

int numBands = raster.getNumBands();

int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {//width...

  for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {

    double[] latlon = geo(geometry, i, j);
    double lat = latlon[0];
    double lon = latlon[1];

    Double s = 0d;

    String originalBands = "";
    for (int k = 0; k < numBands; k++) {
      double d = raster.getSampleDouble(i, j, k);
      originalBands += d + ",";
      s += d;
    }

    originalBands = originalBands.substring(0, originalBands.length() - 1);
    if (s.compareTo(0d) == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    String geoHash = GeohashUtils.encodeLatLon(lat, lon);
    //here do something with the bands, lat, long, geohash, etc....

    }

   }

   }

  private static double[] geo(GridGeometry2D geometry, int x, int y) throws Exception {

  //int zoomlevel = 1;
  Envelope2D pixelEnvelop = geometry.gridToWorld(new GridEnvelope2D(x, y, 1, 1));

  // pixelEnvelop.getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getName().getCodeSpace();
  return new double[]{pixelEnvelop.getCenterY(), pixelEnvelop.getCenterX()};

 }

 }
```

JDK Jars

[image: JDK images jar]

Other Jars

[image: Part1]

[image: part2]

I also added classpath variable for GeoTools jars

[image: classpath]

Edit:

My jai is working without GeoTools Integration, but when I add `gt-geotiff-14.4.jar` it try to add `JAI-core-1.1.3.jar` which conflicts with `jai-core.jar` in my JDK 1.7. So I removed `JAI-core-1.1.3.jar` and related jars but still it gives me same error.

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace please?

Comment: it is copied above in the start of the question. But I found the answer the jars were conflicting. So no need of more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally it worked when I removed Geotiff `jai-core-1.1.3.jar`,`jai-codec-1.1.3.jar` and `jai-imageio-1.1.jar` files and added new class for jai-ext's [gt-utility](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/tree/master/jt-utilities) class files. I just copied from github and added to src of my project.**gt-utility** was the one which was missing. The jars were conflicting too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `jai-core.jar` to your classpath

Comment: @ParthTrivedi where you have added, Show how you start your program

Comment: I am using eclipse in which JDK 1.7 is added, JAI is installed snapshot shows jai jars with no access restriction and i set memory options too '-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m' Now it gives me this error.

Comment: I also used checked the checkboxes in order and export.

Comment: You are sure you have added it to the classpath not the build path?

Comment: No I just added to the build path, let me check with steps to add in class path.

Comment: yes in class path jai codec and jai core is there already along with the whole JRE jdk library

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [GeoTools setup instructions](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/build/install/jdk.html) which say for the JAI
:

> Java Advanced Imaging Java Advanced Imaging is an image processing
>   library allowing you to form chains of operations to process rasters
>   in a manner similar to functional programming.
>
> References:
>
> http://java.net/projects/jai-core Download this Version of JAI
>
> Java Advanced Imaging API 1.1.3 At the time of writing Oracle is
>   migrating java projects around - try the following:
>
> http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/
>   http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html
>   Download JAI for your JDK by clicking on the link for your platform:
>
> Example: jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe
>
> Use the one click installer to install JAI into your JDK
>
> Download JAI for your JRE by clicking on the link for your platform:
>
> Example: jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe
>
> Use the one click installer to install JAI into your JRE
>
> (If you are working on linux you will of course need to choose the
>   appropriate download)

Comment: jai-1_1_2-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe and jai-1_1_2-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe,  I reinstalled and they are correctly appearing in my eclipse as the jars are showing also the error for access restriction also solved, now only this error is coming for initialization of JAI class.

Comment: All the steps are followed from that site, also the full permission is given to whole JDK folder as well as JRE folder still there is error.

Comment: GeoTools 14.x is also for JDK1.7 and jai-1_1_2-lib is also for JDK 1.7.